# IntentDialog matches only once at the start in bot framework

Tags: bots, botframework, chatbot

I have a simple piece of code where I want to run a first run operation in the beginning and let the default dialog handle everything else. In the code below.

```
bot.dialog('/firstRun', [firstRun1])
function firstRun1(session) {
    session.replaceDialog('/')
}

bot.dialog('/', new builder.IntentDialog()
    .matches(/wishlist/, '/wishlist')
    .matches(/exclusive/, '/exclusive')
    .onDefault('/runCampaign')
)
bot.dialog('/wishlist', (session, args) => {
    session.endDialog('Add to wishlist')
})

bot.dialog('/exclusive', (session, args) => {
    session.endDialog('Exclusive')
})

bot.dialog('/runCampaign', [runCampaign1])

function runCampaign1(session) {
    session.send('default')
}
```

My problem is right here. When the person types exclusive I believe the default dialog will run its matches and should ideally trigger exclusive no matter how many times but for some reason its not happening that way as per the screenshot below. Once a person types exclusive or wishlist at the start it always runs the default at the bottom, how can I fix this. Also how to share data commonly between the different match clauses in the IntentDialog, lets say I want to have some variable session.dialogData.name across the matches and the default
[image]
UPDATE 1
Instead of saying session.endDialog inside the 2 areas in my code above, I simply wrote session.send() without ending any dialogs and now nothing happens when i type exclusive or wishlist. Am I missing something?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should always call `session.endDialog` if you want to return to the calling(previous) dialog.

In your first example:

```
|current dialog|user input|next dialog|
|first run     |go        | /         |
| /            |whishlist | /         |
| /            |freak     |runCampaign|
|runCampaign   |<any>     |runCampaign|
```

as you didn't call `session.endDialog` in the `runCampaign` dialog, you will always be in it and on any user input the 'default' will be printed.

In you second example, you missed to type "whishlist", so you immediately got into the `runCampaign` dialog. So, you changes to `send` there not called. But if you were typed 'whislist' as in the first example before "freak", you would have gotten into `wishlist` and you would always have printed "Added to wishlist" on any input.

Comment: but i thought we arent supposed to close the default dialog. is it fine if we close it

Comment: Actually, you don't end the default dialog, you end the runCampaign dialog that is called from onDefault from the root dialog. The root dialog is still running.

Comment: any ideas about this part of the question "Also how to share data commonly between the different match clauses in the IntentDialog" :)

Comment: As you started new dialogs in the intent dialog, you cannot use `session.dialogData`. But you can use `session.privateConversationData` that keeps the data for this user conversation.